# CLASSIC ASP, using hyperlink in a variable in table

Tags: asp-classic

Hello  I have a question, I would like to use hyperlink as a variable in my table, I tried this code but it gives error

```vb
<%

set conn1 = server.createobject("adodb.connection")

conn1.open "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web\database.accdb" 

set rs1 = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs1.open " select cityID, city_img, city_name, city_population, city_description, city_link from city order by cityID", conn1

x = "<table border = 1 width=500><tr><th><th><th>Name<th>City Population<th>City Description<th>Show the list</tr>"
response.write x
rs1.movefirst

while not rs1.eof

   x = "<tr><td>" & "<td><img src=img\" & rs1("city_img") & " height=200 width=200>" & "<td>" &  rs1("city_name") & "<td>" & rs1("city_population") & "<br>" & "Million" & "<td>" & rs1("city_description") & "<td>" & "<a href=""" & rs1("city_link") & """>" & show list & "</a>""</tr>"
   response.write x
   rs1.movenext

wend
response.write "</table>"

rs1.close
conn1.close
set rs1 = nothing

%>
```

Comment: Your string concatenation could use some work, you don’t need to concatenate literal strings together only when wanting to include code elements like variables and functions. Also, the HTML is not correctly structured *(td tag without closing tag etc)*. Fix these problems first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error near:

```
"<a href=""" & rs1("city_link") & """>"
```

Your double quotes are escaping the code and trying to put it back together without an '&' symbol.

This should fix it:

```
"<a href='" & rs1("city_link") & "'>"
```

My guess is that you tried to use a double quote because a single quote is a comment in clasisc asp, but you are in a string here, so that gets taken out of the equation.

Comment: Actually, that is perfect valid for escaping double quotes in VBScript strings. It's not the best formatted string i’ve ever seen though.

Comment: Substituting double quotes for single quotes is just lazy and shouldn’t be the accepted answer. Then again this isn’t the clearest of questions.

Comment: The main issue they have is their HTML in the string is not formed correctly.